# Disable Oracle auditing for a particular user?

Tags: oracle, audit

I have one application user in my Oracle 11g DB which does logins/logouts very often.

Since this user is not a human, but an application I would like to exclude the login and logout actions of this particular user from my audit log.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "audit..." command option to exclude selected users.

you can do it by enabling audit for all other users, example:

```
audit update table, delete table, 
      insert table by TESTUSER by access;
```